Generate ast by value
The following example shows how to build an ast using a source expression and a value.
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "go/ast"
    "go/parser"
)

func main() {
    source := "[]byte{1,2,3}"
    exp1, err := parser.ParseExpr(source)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    ast.Print(nil, exp1)

    value := []byte{1, 2, 3}
    exp2, err := parser.ParseExpr(fmt.Sprintf("%#v", value))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    ast.Print(nil, exp2)

}

Is it possible to do the second directly without Sprintf using reflection?

No. No is too short for an answer.
